# Happy Birthday Roger Planes

Tags: c#, command-line

I'm try write my friend an application which says happy birthday what's the best way to write this to be run in the background and then pop-up around 5pm today...?

Comment: Thanks guys sorry to have misused the service it was really just a way of publishing a happy birthday message for my friend through the geekiest medium I know!!! ;)

Comment: FWIW: in cmd.exe `at 17:00 /interactive wordpad.exe "C:\happybirthday.rtf"`. Create the file using wordpad. Perhaps you need to start the scheduler as well: `net start "task scheduler"`. That's geeky and you can use large bold fonts and colors :)

Answer (score 2):

Use window services + Timer, Please see below:

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c6919

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the system scheduler to run this application, you can make it as simple as runing the command prompt and echo your text or make a full standalone exe file.

Opening an url is another story. I would run a command prompt and execute the browser with the url with your happy birthday text:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.yoururl.com
```

*note: i opened the url with IE, it's the most common windows browser.